# ERD generator tool for Rails 2.3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erd

SA

I want and ERD Generator that understands the relations between Rails Models.

I found Railroad but did not work with 2.3.2

I found also http://rails-erd.rubyforge.org/ but it is for Rails 3

Any idea?